# Control spacing of floating form field label in Flutter to field on focus / content

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm currently writing a form in Flutter, and first wanted to code a `CupertinoTextFormFieldRow` with the styles of the validation error message customized. As it seems, this is actually not possible with this widget, but only via the `InputDecoration` widget, which is only available for the `decoration` property of the `TextFormField` widget. So step 1 of this problem consisted in forgetting about `CupertinoTextFormFieldRow`.

After digging into `TextFormField`, what I now miss is a way to control the vertical spacing of the floating form field label to the field on focus / content. As a concrete example, you may provide input to the text field in [this example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/label.html) and compare the position of the floating label with the one obtained if you provide input in [this example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/floatingLabelStyle.html). The only difference I really see is that the latter uses `OutlineInputBorder` as the `border` property of the `InputDecoration` being used, while the first example uses nothing for that `border` property at all. Is that how you do it, or am I misunderstanding something?